# Create Nav/indicators on page based on tags

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, d3.js

I am building an offline HTML page based on the text file.  The text file has some tags which we want to use to navigate on the page (also to indicate where certain tag exists in the text proportionately on the horizontal bar on top)  I am using python to create this page but not sure what would I go about create something like the image below using JavaScript or D3.Js?

I want to create to top bar which indicate proportionately where certain tag exits in the text

Any guidance would be really helpful

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can split the text into an array of lines based on character or word length, taking into account line breaks to separate paragraphs. Then you could analyze each line and build another array containing tag information for each line (either using RegEx or just `string.includes`, depending on the requirements), and take that information into account when rendering the page (possibly replacing some strings in the text with `<a>` links.

The top bar can be built using DOM elements (simple `div`s with width equal to `1/lines.length` as `inline-block`s or regular `block`s in a `flex` container), SVG or canvas.

Comment: Thanks. I have already created the html file with anchor tags, but not sure how to go about create the top bar.  I need to add lines based on the proportion of the size of the full text, so if desired tag (e.g. 'PagerMaker' word) appears almost at the end of page, then the line on the top bar should be towards the end of bar.

Comment: @SharePointer Is the bar displayed per page or for the entire document? You can further split the lines into pages, with a given limit of lines per page, and follow the same recipe - add a `div` for each line with width equal to `1/linesPerPage`, and if it contains any tags color it appropriately.

Comment: The whole file is in a single page, but I think I can take total word count I think

Comment: So the bar is displayed based on the currently visible lines?

Comment: I think I have to draw bar based on the total word count. Let's say I have 1000 words, I can draw 10 lines and highlight the line where word is appearing. so if word/tag is appearing at the position of 890, I can highlight the 9th bar.